# JAXB XML generation

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to know how I can generate the following using JAXB.

Main problem - having two namespaces in soapenv. When I make the xml and then add the soap env, it adds name spaces in different lines. This is not the way I want it

Problem 2 - instead of xmlsn="..." I want xmlns:SOME_TEXT="..." as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:fis="http://fis.certegy.cka.com/">
<soapenv:Body>
 <fis:InquiryRequest>
 <Version>1.0</Version>
 <RequestUID>191919191919191</RequestUID>
 <Station>1078686704</Station>
 <TranType>40</TranType>
 <Consumer>
 <FirstName>Susie</FirstName>
 <LastName>Smith</LastName>
 <Address>
 <Line1>100 59th</Line1>
 <Line2>Ave NE</Line2>
 <City>New York</City>
 <State>NY</State>
 <Zip>10021</Zip>
 </Address>
 <Phone>1114589658</Phone>
 <EmailAddress>Your.Email@yahoo.com</EmailAddress>
 <DateOfBirth>1960-01-01</DateOfBirth>
 <ID>
 <Type>NY</Type>
 <Value>285756967</Value>
 </ID>
 <DeviceID>12345678000</DeviceID>
 <DaysOfEmployment>9991</DaysOfEmployment>
 <PayDate>2019-05-03</PayDate>
 <PayFrequency>Weekly</PayFrequency>
 </Consumer>
 <Amount>70.00</Amount>
 <CashBack>0</CashBack>
 <GiftCard>0</GiftCard>
 <Check>
 <Micr>
 <ExpansionType>1002</ExpansionType>
 <Line>T861000016A100002106C</Line>
 <Swiped>false</Swiped>
 </Micr>
 <Type>P</Type>
 </Check>
 </fis:InquiryRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note: I am using the `EclipseLink MOXY` which is an extension of the `JAXB` and provides a lot of additional benefits compared to normal `JAXB`. The below answer is based on the `MOXY` not sure if it would work even for `Standard JAXB`.

I am not sure if I have understood your problem 1 correctly. Based on my understanding when you solve the `problem-2` then I am guessing it should solve this as well. As it will add all the namespaces to the header of the `XML` in your case `soapenv:Envelope`.

With regards to your problem 2:
If you would like to obtain the custom `prefix` for your `namespace URI` then you can create a `Map<String, String>` with your `prefix` and `namespace` and pass it during the `marshaling` so the `moxy` would automatically handle and provide the `prefix` to header (`xmlns`) and your XML `node`.

```
Map<String, String> namespaces = new HashMap<String, String>();
namespaces.put("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "soapenv");
namespaces.put("http://fis.certegy.cka.com/", "fis");
namespaces.put("Whatever your namespace", "SOME_TEXT");
jsonMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
jsonMarshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.NAMESPACE_PREFIX_MAPPER, namespaces);
jsonUnmarshaller.setProperty(UnmarshallerProperties.JSON_NAMESPACE_PREFIX_MAPPER, namespaces);
```

Reference [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/solutions/json002.htm#:%7E:text=Task%205%20Using%20Namespaces)

GitHub [code](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink)